# Cache API doesn't work on safari ios simulator and on mac

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, caching

I am trying to use the following snippet code in my `index.html`.

```js
<script>
        fetch('index1.js').then(response => {
            caches.open('test-cache').then(cache => {
                cache.put('index1.js', response);
            })
        })
    </script>
```

I have a custom domain on localhost called `test-website.com`. When I access this page through chrome, all is good and `index1.js` gets stored in cache. Now, I turn on `ios Simulator` and open safari in there and run the same website again. I also check this website on mac safari, but In the console, this is what I get:

> Unhandled Promise Rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable:
>   caches

**Question 1)** Why do I get this error?

**Question 2)** I checked the compatibility: [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) and [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache). The first one has compatibility with `ios safari` , second one doesn't. What's the difference between these 2? and could this be the reason why it can't find the cache?

**Question 3)** Apple supports service worker and it should be supporting `Cache API`. Otherwise it has no worth . Any idea?

Comment: I've had the same issue on prod, when the SW's installed event is fired, I trigger  `caches.open` but `caches` is undefined in the global scope. Some possible race condition?

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for [Cache Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CacheStorage) states the following:

> Note: Chrome and Safari only expose `CacheStorage` to the windowed context over HTTPS. window.caches will be undefined unless an SSL certificate is configured.

Ensure that you are serving and accessing the webpage over HTTPS

As far as I know, the browser will still allow the `caches` variable to be accessible when serving pages from `localhost` as a means to do testing, but this rule should not apply if you're accessing it over a custom domain `test-website.com`

Comment: This is ridiculous. Leave it to apple.

Answer (score 0):

cache api WORKS on safari !

I think I can answer questions 2 and 3.
I was frustrated because I couldn't check whether my cache API logic was working properly in Safari or not.This is because the cache data was not visible in Safari developer tools.

**How to check whether the cache API works in Safari.**
With Safari browser Developer Tools - Network tab turned on, try sending the API request to be cached twice.
If Safari caches, the network response will only come once.